# How to start a command in tmux + urxvt setup?

Tags: linux, tmux, urxvt

I'm trying to make a pretty nice desktop console which can show system logs from /dev/logi . The device displays new content from several files in /var/log . I want to use urxvt and tmux to do so. Everything seems to be working, but I have no idea how to autostart it. I'm using openbox, so I tried adding the following line to /home/morfik/.config/openbox/autostart :

```
(sleep 2 && urxvt -name 'konsola_desktop' -e sh -c "tmux -c 'cat /dev/logi'") &
```

This doesn't work as expected. urxvt stars and if something is logged, it is displayed on the console. But one part is missing, there's no tmux. I need it because I set in /home/morfik/.Xresources the following option:

```
URxvt*saveLines: 0
```

and I use tmux buffer specified in /etc/tmux.conf :

```
set -g history-limit 5000
```

So, if I start the command above, I'm not able to scroll output. I can't even divide screen because tmux isn't there. There's also no tmux process:

```
ps -eo "%mem args" | grep -i tmux
1.1 urxvt -name konsola_desktop -e sh -c tmux -c 'cat /dev/logi'
0.0 sh -c tmux -c 'cat /dev/logi'
```

But when I just do the following steps:

```
urxvt -name 'konsola_desktop'
tmux
cat /dev/logi
```

everything works just fine:

```
ps -eo "%mem args" | grep -i tmux
0.1 tmux
0.1 tmux
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: The `-c` option is the problem here: it just acts as a “pass through” to a shell (*tmux*’s configured `default-shell`)—this is usually only useful when *tmux* is configured as a user’s login shell (since other programs might assume the login shell knows how to handle args like `-c shell_cmd_str`). You probably want to use `new-session` instead of `-c`.

Comment: I defined two sessions in tmux config file, and now I'm using `(sleep 2 && urxvt -name 'cdesktop' -e bash -c "tmux attach-session -t logi") &`, and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

First off all, it's better to use tmux config file instead of putting a command in the autostart line. So, it would be:

```
new true
set set-remain-on-exit on
new -n logi "cat /dev/logi"
neww -n test
splitw -v -p 50 -t 0 
neww -n test2
splitw -h -p 50 -t 0
set -u set-remain-on-exit
```

The above lines should be added to /etc/tmux.conf , and now the line that starts the console should look like this:

```
(sleep 2 && urxvt -name 'konsola_desktop' -e bash -c "tmux attach") &
```

It's even better because I can define multiple windows and switch between them.